# Boto3 ECR paginator loop

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am using the below code to return a list of versions from ECR. The issue is that the version I am trying to compare is on page 2. But the loop exits after the first page because the ECR image is not on the first page but the second. What is the best way to only exit after the comparison has gone thru all the pages.

```
for page in response_iterator:
  images = page['imageIds']
  for image in images:
    if image['imageTag'] == version:
      print('image found')
      break
  else:
    print('ECR not found')
    exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, one simple solution is to keep a counter, for example:

```
count_match = 0

for page in response_iterator:
    images = page['imageIds']
    for image in images:
        if image['imageTag'] == version:
            print('image found')
            count_match = count_match + 1
            break

if count_match == 0:
    print('ECR not found')
    exit(1)
```